# Proof of the integral representation of the arithmetic mean of the partial sums of Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, fourier-series, cesaro-summable

The definition and the formula in question:[image]

[image]

The equations he refers to:
[image]
.................................................................................................................................................................
[image]

.................................................................................................................................................................
[image]

Obtaining the formula seems straight forward but It has been quite difficult for me for some reason. My problem is with the term $$\frac{\sin^{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}nt\right)}{\sin^{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}t\right)}$$
and I get the denominator easily, but I can't get the numerator right and I checked my steps for errors multiple times.

Comment: It's just formula (16), applied to the numerators of the Dirichlet kernel: $$\sum_{k = 1}^n \sin \bigl((2k-1)\frac{t}{2}\bigr) = \frac{\sin^2\bigl(n\frac{t}{2}\bigr)}{\sin \frac{t}{2}}.$$

Comment: It's a plus sign in the Dirichlet kernel and a minus in formula (16). Sorry I don't see how they are the same

Comment: But in formula (16), $k$ runs from $1$ to $n$, while in $\sigma_n = \frac{1}{n}(s_0 + \ldots + s_{n-1})$ the index runs from $0$ to $n-1$. And note $2m + 1 = 2(m+1)-1$. (Yes, index shifts can throw one off)